# How to install pygtk within virtualenv?

Tags: python, gtk, ipython

I installed ipython in a virtual env (1.13 with 2.7.2) and tried `ipython -gui=gtk` but still got the basic terminal interface with no %paste support for example.

Now I tried installing pygtk but no success there either.

I'm running Crunchbang linux with OpenBox WM.

```
    [TerminalIPythonApp] GUI event loop or pylab initialization failed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
...python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.pyc in enable_gui(gui, app)
    526         e = "Invalid GUI request %r, valid ones are:%s" % (gui, guis.keys())
    527         raise ValueError(e)
--> 528     return gui_hook(app)
    529 

...python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/inputhook.pyc in enable_gtk(self, app)
    286         IPython.
    287         """
--> 288         import gtk
    289         try:
    290             gtk.set_interactive(True)

ImportError: No module named gtk
```

I've tried to pip install pygtk within the virtualenv I've activated but no luck.

Full log:

```
$ pip install pygtk
Downloading/unpacking pygtk
  Downloading pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2 (2.4MB): 2.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pygtk
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************

* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *

* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *

********************************************************************

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in ...python2.7/build/pygtk
```

Comment: Two things - first, you need to be running this from a terminal from a GUI session (like gnome), and second, the argument needs to be prefixed with two `--` like this: `ipython --gui=gtk`. If it still doesn't work; edit your question with the error message you get.

Comment: I think this is a question for the pygtk mailing list. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: You program using ipython. There are loads of valid questions on here regarding programming environments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running a debian-based distribution; you can save yourself some headaches and simply `sudo apt-get install ipython` (and `sudo apt-get install ipython3` if you want to play with Python 3).

This will ensure that the proper GTK bindings are installed as well.  This is the *most supported way*.

Latest versions of ipython have auto-detection of virtualenvironments.

Comment: what do you mean auto-detection? So if I install it with my os python and run it inside an active virtualenv it will run inside that?

Comment: also the latest version via this method appears to be 0.10, and so running with gui switch is not supported, so I'm not sure how to start this.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your issue, but try giving the latest version string to apt-get install:

        sudo apt-get install ipython=0.13.1

Answer (score 0):

I first installed gi with pip (on ubuntu) and got the same error, without a virtualenv. My solution was to uninstall gi:
`sudo -H pip uninstall gi`
and then install using:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi`