# Pygtk min virtualenv fails to install

Tags: python, pygtk

I am trying to install pygtk via pip on a GNU/Linux machine with a freshly created virtualenv I try to install pygtk via pip using this command:

```
pip install pygtk
```

But I get the following error:

```
Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qcLrwN/pygtk/
```

Furthermore I have seen the following questions:

- [How to install pygtk within virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782776/how-to-install-pygtk-within-virtualenv)
- [Struggling to install pygtk with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323732/struggling-to-install-pygtk-with-pip)

But still No light in my path

### Edid 1:

I typed these command lines on my terminal:

```
mkvirtualenv pygtkexample --system-site-packages
workon pygtkexample
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
pip install pygtk
```

And I still get the very same error.

Comment: The idea is that you no longer need to install pygtk ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..as the error tells you, you cannot build PyGTK this way in Linux.

you can create your environment with `virtualenv --system-site-packages` and then install other packages you want to use in this specific environment with `pip install --ignore-installed`, because these will locally be prioritized over the system-wide packages.

Alternatively, you can manually clone from git and build GTK.

In case you are using `virtualenvwrapper` type:

```
mkvirtualenv ^env_name^ --system-site-packages
```

As workaround, you can try to forego installing GTK in your venv, by using something along the lines of the following to import the system-wide package manually:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk")
```

Comment: How can I do it with virtualenvwrapper

Comment: virtualenvwrapper is just a wrapper for virtualenv. Should not be radically different, right? `https://saurabh-kumar.com/blog/virtualenv-vs-virtualenvwrapper.html` provides you with a nice blog post which adds the benefits of virtualenvwrapper to virtualenv, so you will no longer require the added layer

Answer (score 0):

Created a Virtualenv without the `--system-site-packages`. Just set the `PYTHON_PATH` enviromental variable to the value:

```
export PYTHON_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python
```

Afterwards install:

```
pip install vext.pygtk
```

Then via the command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

you can put it into system's requirements.